# Проверяю subprocess.Popen с функций .poll() но после чего закриваю внешний.exe получаю None

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Доброе время суток.
Я создал класс Checker и две функций, одно создаёт label а другая функция у которая обновляет label зависимости что я открываю.
Этот клас рабоатет в петле с окрытия.

Часть кода :

```
    link_proto=("E:\____GEMIS2.0\ENEL_Gemis_2_Log_Extractor_v3.exe")
    nameProc= subprocess.Popen(link_proto)
    nameProg = "Proto"
    poll = nameProc.poll()#### это я забыл добавить



class Checker:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.label = tk.Label(root,bg = 'white',bd=5,width=33,font=('Arial', 13,'bold'))
        canvas1.create_window(595, 100, window=self.label)
        self.label.after(1000, self.refresh_label)
    def refresh_label(self):
        try :
            if poll is None:
                self.label.configure(text='Proto')
        except NameError:
            self.label.configure(text='None')      
        self.label.after(1000, self.refresh_label)

checker = Checker(root)
```

Когда `nameProc= subprocess.Popen(link_proto)` закрыт label показывает `"None"`
Когда откриваю `nameProc= subprocess.Popen(link_proto)` label показывает `"Proto"`

Проблема вот тут когда я закрывают из винды этот link_proto , label не обновляется `"None"`

Я думаю что проблема в  `poll is None`..

После чего я закрываю из виндо `poll` остается `None`

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема или как решить.

Comment: Вы пишете про функцию poll, но пытаетесь обратиться к переменной poll, которой у вас нет (из-за этого и вылетает NameError). Скорее всего вам нужно вызывать метод poll от nameProc: `nameProc.poll()`

Comment: я забил добавить переменую, сечас добавил.
У меня залитает в  NameError когда nameProc= subprocess.Popen(link_proto) закрыто и меняется label  когда окрываю , но когда закрываю из виндо то poll is None полюбому.

Comment: nameProc.poll() нужно вызывать не один раз в начале программы, а постоянно в вашем чекере.

Comment: Ты прав , спасибо тебе огромное!